# Import a file without actually importing it

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, require, fs

I'm creating a package that will get a JavaScript object from the user and do some things with that. All users need to do is to write the file name. Like so `node package.js file.js`.

I use something like this:

```
  const object = require(process.argv[2]);
```

But linter gives me this `import/no-dynamic-require` and also webpack throws a warning like:

```
30:14-27 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
```

So what do you think is the best way to use that file?

Comment: You can dynamically load and run code yourself with `fs.readFile()` and `eval()`.  Not sure what else you really need as I can't tell what you're really trying to accomplish.

Comment: Your error messsage implies that maybe you're using something like webpack.  If that's the case, it analyzes all dependencies at bundle time so you can't use variables with `require()` because it's pre-bundling everything that you import.

Comment: Please describe how you are bundling and running this code?  You can use an expression with `require()` if you aren't using a bundler and if you are running on a server (not in the browser).

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
//TODO: copy contents of input file specified to temp file myObscurelyNamedTempFile.js

const object = require('./myObscurelyNamedTempFile.js');

//TODO: delete temp file after package completes its work
```

In the package documentation, warn users not to create a file of the temporary name

Comment: If the OP is using something like webPack that analyzes dependencies at compile time (not at run time), which it appears they might be based on the error then this won't work as they will get a static version of the tempfile, not the newly written version.